# Binary trees, construct a tree based on preorder

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, data-structures, binary-tree

constructing a tree given it's inorder is easy enough.
But, let's say you are supposed to construct a tree based on it's preorder (`+ + y z + * x y z` for example).

It's easy to see that `+` is the root, and how to continue in the left subtree from there. 
But.. how do you know when you are supposed to "switch" to the right subtree?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, inorder is considered the difficult case.

For preorder, you'll just have a grammar like this.

```
expr ::= operator expr expr | var
```

An operator is followed by **exactly two well-formed expressions**. This can be parsed easily using recursion

If you parse a tree and get a variable, return the variable.
If you parse a tree and get an operator, parse the two following trees as right/left subtrees.